# How common was poisoning as tool of murder among common people in 19th and early 20th century Europe?

Tags: everyday-life, crime, family

We all know famous people who were murdered by poisoning from ancient times till today. I am not interested in this, I am more interested in average people killing their spouses, relative (maybe friends, enemies) with poison.

Up till early-mid 20th century poisoning was the perfect murder:

- no obvious sign;
- many poisons were very hard to detect even when suspected;
- easy access even for the common people as many household chemicals contained them.

Unfortunately, I have found very few documented cases (most probably because of the difficulty of study it retrospectively). The most famous one is maybe the [AngelMakers of Tiszazug](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel_Makers_of_Nagyr%C3%A9v) after WWI, where wives murdered their husbands and other relatives in large number. There are some interesting differences between the English and [Hungarian version](https://hu.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiszazugi_m%C3%A9regkever%C5%91k) of the wiki, including the estimated number of victims (50ish vs 300ish), and Hungarian wiki clearly mentions that similar (less famous) cases happened in the neighborhood and other part of the country, too. Authorities generally tried to hide these cases, to avoid scandal, which I guess makes their research even more difficult.

So the question: do we have any estimation, how common form of domestic murder poisoning was?

Comment: I'm not sure this is something answerable (though that doesn't mean someone hasn't researched it). But, as you say, if there are "no obvious signs" then it's quite likely there wouldn't be much to base any research on except for rumours and statements of dubious quality.

Comment: I think it's pushing things to say that "poisoning was the perfect murder". Some poisons (such as arsenic) were detectable post-mortem and some (such as cyanide and strychnine) had distinctive symptoms.

Comment: Citation needed that many poisons are hard to detect.  If that were true (I am skeptical) then we're very unlikely to have any records of poisonings.  The only way we'd have records is if either (a) there were unsuccessful attempts or (b) the perpetrators confessed - which would be astonishing.  This may be an unanswerable question.

Comment: @SteveBird If 100 years ago an average person died without a bullet or a knife in the body, there were little chance for autopsy. Especially in poor areas or countryside. That is as close as possible to a perfect murder for someone who cannot sign his or her name.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace “Many” is not equal “all”, “were” is not equal to “are”.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is answerable as is, but the ease of murder by poison was something that historical society seriously grappled with. So that might be an indication that it is not, at least, very rare. @Greg I mean if you put it like that, for most of history you could just feed a corpse to a pig or dump it in the sea / wilds and no one would know. Poisoning may not be immediately incriminating but all it takes is one person getting suspicious: see for instance how Mary Ann Cotton got busted.

Comment: Downvoted because - as with pretty much all crime statistics - it is unanswerable.  We can only know about cases where poisoning was detected, and even then we have in general no way of knowing for sure whether deaths were deliberate poisonings, or accidental (e.g. picking the wrong mushrooms, or including foxglove leaves in your salad).

Comment: @Semaphore Thanks for the comment. As far as I know Mary Ann Cotton got busted, because she was a serial killer (20 victims or so). The initial verdict of her final victim was “natural cause”, and her downfall was that journalists dug up the suspicious death of her mother, many of her husbands and children with very similar symptoms.

Comment: @Greg Not due to journalists. Mary Ann Cotton was caught when she got careless and told Thomas Riley that her stepson was inconveniencing her plans, but "it won't matter" because he'll soon die. *Then he died.* Riley naturally went to the authorities, hence Dr Kilburn declined to issue a death certificate. Though he failed to determine a cause of death in time for the 13 July inquest (leading to the "natural causes" verdict you mentioned), he saved the stomach contents for further tests. This revealed the poisoning on 17 July, whereupon he went to the police. Cotton was arrested the next day.

Comment: @Semaphore Thanks for clarification.